# When will windows uuid change on the same system

Tags: windows, uuid

I'm wondering about what the Windows UUID that you can get with "wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get uuid" really comes from and when it will change. Microsoft says, the UUID comes from the SMBIOS information (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394105(v=vs.85).aspx), what seems to me that the UUID only depends on the system's BIOS. So what when I do one of the following things:

- (a) Reinstall Windows on the same system
- (b) Install a second Windows on the same system
- (c) Clone windows to another disk and then use this disk in the same system

Will any of this actions make the UUID to be changed? Or is it possible to have to different Windows systems with the same UUID (b)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

None of these actions will change the UUID. The UUID is a machine-unique ID, like a serial number. It is stored on the motherboard (typically in the system flash eeprom, along with the BIOS) and reported by the BIOS to the OS in an SMBIOS structure, as you guessed.

Answer (score 0):

In theory Windows/SMBIOS UUID is designed to be constant and unique. So that, theoretically it won't change if you would do any of (a), (b) or (c).

However situation on practice is different, as many hardware vendors use the same UUID for bunch of boards, or just use dummy non-unique values like: 00020003000400050006000700080009.

Moreover, it was reported that UUID can change on every computer restart, see this post for more details:  http://howtowriteaprogram.blogspot.jp/2012/06/smbios-uuid-fail.html